# Signtool fails on jenkins build with timeserver specified

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, signtool

When running MSBuild via Jenkins, the build fails at the signing process as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\Build-EngineeringApps.proj(178,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe" sign /v /f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\certificate.pfx" /p [Password redacted] /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\Setup\Release\setup.exe"" exited with code 255.
```

Running MSBuild from the developer command prompt is successful. Running the above command from the command prompt is also successful.

If the timeserver is removed from the command, Jenkins builds successfully. i.e.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\Build-EngineeringApps.proj(178,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe" sign /v /f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\certificate.pfx" /p [Password redacted] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\engsoft\eng-software\Setup\Release\setup.exe"" exited with code 255.
```

The jenkins service is configured to run under the administrator account. This is the same account that can successfully build via MSBuild as above. The certificate has been added to the store under this user also.